# Anchor tag with an id in JSP

Tags: html, jsp, jsp-tags, web-development-server

```
<td id="domainName_<s:property value="#rowstatus.index"/>"><s:property
                        value="domainName" /></td>
```

I want to make domainName_XXXX as Clickable href with a link and I'm unable to figure out how to use the  tag or any other with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this you can use `anchor` tag like...

```
<td><a href="domainName_<s:property value="#rowstatus.index"/>"<s:property
                    value="domainName" /></td>
```

Comment: then where will I be putting my link like google.com so that it can redirect it

Comment: You can put your link in `href` attribute